# How to grep exact word with only space as word separator

Tags: grep, regular-expression

For Example: I have file like following:

```
AA ABC-AA-AA
AAA ABC-AA
ABC.AA ABC
AA ABC.A AA
```

If I use `grep -w "ABC" file1`, I am getting all the lines.

But I should only get 3rd line: `ABC.AA ABC`

It is taking `.` and `-` as word separators. But I need only space as word separator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From (GNU) `grep(1)` man page:

> **-w, --word-regexp**
>
> Select only those lines containing matches that  form  whole  words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be  either at the  end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. ***Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore***.

Thus you'll need to explicitly request the spaces (or line beginnings and/or ends) to be there:

```
grep -E '(^| )ABC( |$)' file1
```

If you also want to include other white-space characters, replace the spaces above with a larger set, e.g. `[[:space:]]` (again see the `grep(1)` man page).