# Search string using grep

Tags: grep

In my `file_*.txt` there are two type of words one containing `LC1` only and another containing `LC1_R`.

I would like to `grep` lines that contain only `LC1` not `LC1_R`. How can I do it?

I tried:

```
grep "LC1" file_*.txt
```

then I am getting both lines that contains `LC1` as well as those lines which contains `LC1_R` also.

Comment: I bet this's a duplicated question, but I can't find the old one, now.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. But, before putting question here I googled it and also search it on Stack-exchange, when I was not able to find it. Then I posted it here. May be my way of searching was not good. I will try to improve it.

Comment: [This one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/186543/38906) is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\b` to match the word boundary:

```
grep '\bLC1\b' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk  alternative here. You didn't give much idea about contents of your file,so I'll here's an answer that operates on fields (words) in general

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {if ($i=="LC1"){print $0}}}'
```